# How to check if an object is iterable in Python?

Tags: python, iterable

How does one check if a Python object supports iteration, a.k.a an iterable object ([see definition](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable)

Ideally I would like function similar to `isiterable(p_object)` returning True or False (modelled after `isinstance(p_object, type)`).

Answer (score 88):

You can check for this using `isinstance` and `collections.Iterable`

```
>>> from collections.abc import Iterable # for python >= 3.6
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> isinstance(l, Iterable)
True
```

Note: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.9 it will stop working.

Comment: This works only for new-style classes and requires Python 2.6+.

Comment: Just take note that `str` is also iterable.  So if you're thinking `tuple, list, set`.. it might be better to just check for those 3 types

Comment: Use `from collections.abc import Iterable` as importing the ABCs from collections is depracated since Python 3.3

Answer (score 10):

Try this code

```
def isiterable(p_object):
    try:
        it = iter(p_object)
    except TypeError: 
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't "check".  You assume.

```
try:
   for var in some_possibly_iterable_object:
       # the real work.
except TypeError:
   # some_possibly_iterable_object was not actually iterable
   # some other real work for non-iterable objects.
```

It's easier to ask forgiveness than to ask permission.

Comment: Wouldn't this break if something is iterable but has no entries? E.g. if you wanted to tell apart a list and a string, it wouldn't seem like a smart idea to treat it as a string just because the list is empty.

Comment: I disagree with this. Chances are that you'll want to do `if not iterable: [obj]` to assert that something is ALWAYS iterable. More likely to make for cleaner code imo.

Comment: Catches any `TypeError` in “the real work” without a way to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @WillS Absolutely, that's how I do it too. This allows you to create functions allowing parameters that can be either a unique object or a bunch of objects.

Comment: It's generally accepted that one should not use exceptions for non-exceptional (expected) situations. Thus, for something like a function that takes a parameter that may be a single value or a collection of values, `isinstance(x, Iterable)` would be better from that point of view. (In Python, however, one must be careful with strings and bytestrings if you're considering those to be "single" values.)