# I need help coming up with a function in python that can take 3 arguements as lists and give me all combinations of there elements

Tags: python, function, combinations

What I have so far does pretty much nothing

> ```
> def dress_me(shirt, tie, suit):
>
>
>  #    if type(shirt) != list or type(tie) != list or type(suit) != list:
>     #        return None
>             combinations = dress_me(shirt, tie, suit)
>             for combo in combinations:
>                 print(combo)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
def dress_me(shirt, tie, suit):
    if type(shirt) != list or type(tie) != list or type(suit) != list:
        return None
    return list(itertools.product(shirt, tie, suit))
```

Demo:

```
>>> dress_me([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
[(1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1, 5, 9), (1, 6, 7), (1, 6, 8), (1, 6, 9), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 5, 9), (2, 6, 7), (2, 6, 8), (2, 6, 9), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 7), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9), (3, 6, 7), (3, 6, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: I think it would be more Pythonic if there were no list test. Any iterable would actually work. I'm not sure it makes a whole lot of sense to return `None` if one of the inputs is invalid; that seems counter-intuitive. I'd expect an exception if I passed it a non-iterable; it would make tracking my problem down easier. If returning `None` is actually required, then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4668647/1394393) for checking for iterable types.

Comment: Yes. What you say is reasonable. But first I just answer the question the OP seems to want. And then test if is Iterable is no good. What if a string is passed? I would lead to error. try...except is a good choice. I like that too.

Comment: A string is an iterable; you'd get a product of all the characters, which might be exactly what the caller wants. (I checked, and the answer I linked works for strings, at least in 2.7.) I would assume that the programmer calling the function is aware that strings are iterable, and if it's not the output they wanted, they'll see that very quickly.

Comment: If a string is passed, what you get is apprently not the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Or, for completeness, in the generator-fashion without an extra function:

```
import itertools

for combination in itertools.product(shirts, ties, suits):
    whatever_you_want_to_do(combination)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dress_me(shirt, tie, suit):
    all_combinations = []
    for s in shirt:
        for t in tie:
            for su in suit:
                all_combinations.append((s,t,su))
    return all_combination
```

Maybe there is a more pythonic way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you were trying to come up with a recursive solution, here is the general form of it:

```
def all_perms(thing):
    if len(thing) <=1:
        yield thing
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(thing[1:]):
            for i in range(len(perm)+1):
                yield perm[:i] + thing[0:1] + perm[i:]
```

This works for most kinds of iterables.  Demo:

```
In [5]: list(all_perms(('shirt','tie','suit')))
Out[5]: 
[('shirt', 'tie', 'suit'),
 ('tie', 'shirt', 'suit'),
 ('tie', 'suit', 'shirt'),
 ('shirt', 'suit', 'tie'),
 ('suit', 'shirt', 'tie'),
 ('suit', 'tie', 'shirt')]
```

Recursion is difficult to understand at first, but the general form is:

```
if simplest_case:
    return simplest_case
else:
    #recurse
```

In this case, `return` is replaced by `yield` in order to make a generator, which is more memory-friendly.  You still shouldn't expect this to be the best-performing solution, but I'm including it for completeness since "USE ITERTOOLS" doesn't end up teaching you much other than itertools is cool.